# Is it possible to Bind Grid.RowProperty.

Tags: silverlight, c#-4.0, binding

is it possible to Bind `Grid.RowProperty`

```
Border bdr = new Border();
bdr.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, new Binding("RowNo") { Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });
bdr.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, new Binding("ColumnNo") { Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });
```

at compile time no errors abut at runtime give error

**DependencyProperty of type System.Int32 cannot be set on an object of type System.Windows.Data.Binding.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [SetBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc189874%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) not `SetValue`.

```cs
Border bdr = new Border();
bdr.SetBinding(Grid.RowProperty,
    new Binding("RowNo") {
        Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
    });
bdr.SetBinding(Grid.ColumnProperty,
    new Binding("ColumnNo") {
        Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
    });
```